# Bulding chart with filter in google script

Tags: charts

I Have one Googlespreadsheet with data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OzscRIMYdJ0RwWF9jSpru-s3Zry5NkwvIpHlEBj9ElQ/edit?usp=sharing

Then I'd like a script to create a Line Chart with the possibility to  filter a month and Product (view only the selected month and Product)!

Have you a solution for me?

Comment: Yes. Implement it yourself and we'll help you if you have any issues.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38613267/5090771)...